# Why are generator methods constructors?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

Methods when declared as methods (using ES6 enhanced object literals or classes) are not constructors / does NOT have a prototype chain.

But generators when declared via the method syntax, do have a prototype chain and are constructors.

Take the following example - (requires v8)

```
'use strict';
class x {
  *a() { this.b() }
  b() { print('class method'); }
}
let i = new x();
i.a.prototype.b = function() { print('generator method'); };
i.a().next();
(new i.a()).next();
```

Outputs,

```
class method
generator method
```

While adding prototypes to `i.b`, and calling new `i.b()` will throw an error because `i.b` is not a constructor,
I'm able to do `new i.a()`, and `this` inside `*a` gets a different context.

- Why does this difference exist?
- What is the use case for having prototype in generators defined as methods?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely an odd quirk of the ES2015 spec. TC39 actually had a long discussion [back in July](https://github.com/tc39/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2015-07/july-28.md#67-new--generatorfunction), and decided to [make generators non-`new`able](https://github.com/tc39/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2015-07/july-29.md#revisit-67-new--generatorfunction).

The official change to the spec [landed last month](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/171), and while there was a little concern about breaking things, V8 and SpiderMonkey implementors were in favor of going forward, so I would expect to see it stop working soon (and in fact, it already throws a `TypeError` in Firefox Nightly).

Comment: But `f()` still inherits from `f.prototype`, doesn't it?

Comment: Right, and I don't think the spec changes to remove `[[Construct]]` will affect that. The use case for that inheritance (as I understand it) is to easily provide more abstract operations (i.e. methods) built on top of the generator instance's `next` primitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it boils down to the fact that an ES6 generator method returns an object that includes the iterator and iterable protocols which allows generators to work out of the box with language features that can iterate on collections (such as for..of)

From the MDN documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator:

> In order to be iterable, an object must implement the @@iterator method, meaning that the object (or one of the objects up its prototype chain) must have a property with a Symbol.iterator key.

And a good point raised by @bergi is that generator methods do not need to be constructors.

Comment: A generator method does not support the iterable or iterator protocol. The generator object *it returns* does, yes, but any method can return a generator or iterator. It doesn't need to be a constructor for that.